# Preg Match / character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have link .

`http://www.example.com/about`

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is `/about`.
So when I do

`preg_match("/about/i",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),`

it matches the about link.

But if I have to match `www.example.com`, then I saw that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns `/`.

So I used this code

`preg_match("/\//i",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),`

but it dosent work. Why?What is the correct solution to preg match `/`?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to match the / character using preg match

Comment: Not immediately sure what's wrong, I think something to do with escaping the slash in the regex; however, the simplest solution, I believe, would just be "if (server[requesturi] == '/')", since you're not doing a very complex string-search/comparison.

Comment: Ya that can be done, but what is wrong in preg_match() code I wrote above? I wanted to know where is mistake.

Comment: How `it doesn't work`? what do you obtain?

Comment: I did `if(preg_match("/\//i",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) echo 'style="color:rgb(255,255,255);"';` but it dosent apply the color, however when I do it in other links, it applies the color.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the wrong variable. `$SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` only gives you the *relative* name of the request, so in your example you will only get "/about". To get the domain name, use the superglobal `$SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];`.